# Filter and Match function: matches are wrong

Tags: filter, match

In Google sheet: I have two sets of data, both have a column for Object ID. I have to filter and display the rows for Dataset1 that have a match for an Object ID in Dataset 2 (not all will find a match)
I used =FILTER('Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!A2:M,(Match(F2:F,'Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!L2:L,0) )) or =FILTER('Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!A2:M,ISNUMBER(Match(F2:F,'Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!L2:L,0) )) both yield the same result, but the matches are wrong?!? What am I doing wrong and are there other options?!

I used =FILTER('Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!A2:M,(Match(F2:F,'Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!L2:L,0) )) or =FILTER('Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!A2:M,ISNUMBER(Match(F2:F,'Linked Sheet to Survey responses'!L2:L,0) )) both yield the same result, but the matches are wrong?!? What am I doing wrong and are there other options?!

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to solve this without having access to the actual sheets. Can you share links to the sheets themselves? If they contain sensitive data and you can't share them, perhaps you can reproduce the problem in some sheets containing fictional data, and send us links to these sheets?

Comment: I figuered it out, I had inverted the two matching columns, that's why it was giving me crazy match results 